# Fetch all record by filtering nested array of objects in dynamodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

Suppose I have following HR table:

```
HR = {
  id: "11",
  name: "Ahmad",
  designation: "CEO",
  promotion_history: [
    {
      "title": "CFO",
      "comment": "based on better performance",
      "id": 356
    },
    {
      "title": "Specialist"
      "comment": "Promoted with panel approval",
      "id": 244
    },
    {
      "title": "Officer"
      "comment": "Completed internship successfully",
      "id": 234
    },
   {
      "title": "Intern"
      "comment": "Selected based on extra-ordinary academic background",
      "id": 112
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to scan all records in HR table and filter those individuals that has title as "Intern" in promotion_history array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without specifying the entire map, which includes `comment` and `id`.

I suggest using a better data model:

| PK | SK | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID#11 | ID#11 | personal details, current title etc .. |
| ID#11 | JOB#CFO | comment, id etc.... |
| ID#11 | JOB#Specialist | comment, id etc.... |
| ID#11 | JOB#Intern | comment, id etc.... |

Now you can create a Global Secondary Index on SK, which is the title and you can obtain all items which have or had a job title of `Intern`.

`SELECT * FROM mytable.myindex WHERE SK = "JOB#Intern"`